# need a workaround for a "multiple definition" error

Tags: c, arrays, header-files

A toy code illustrating my problem is as follows:

stuff.h:

```
#ifndef STUFF
#define STUFF

int a;
int testarr[]={1,2,3};

#endif
```

fcn.h:

```
#include "stuff.h"
int b[]={5,6,7};
void fcn();
```

main.h:

```
#include "stuff.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

fcn.c:

```
#include "main.h"

void fcn() {
   printf("Hello\n");
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "fcn.h"

int main() {
   fcn();
   printf("HI\n");
}
```

An attempt to compile fails with:

```
/g/pe_19976/fcn_2.o:(.data+0x40): multiple definition of `testarr'
/g/pe_19976/main_1.o:(.data+0x40): first defined here
```

After doing some reading, I realize that defining the array `testarr` in the header file is a problem.  But the thing is, in my real code, several files need access to `testarr` and it needs to have the same assigned values everywhere.  I guess I could put it in `main.h` (?) but even if that would work, in my real code it logically belongs in `stuff.h`.  How do I solve this conundrum?

BTW, based on something else I found, I tried defining `testarr` as `extern` but got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear why you are using so many global variables. The array

```
int testarr[]={1,2,3};
```

is defined as many times as there are compilation units (in your example there are at least two compilation units) that include the corresponding header.

Declare the array in a header like

```
extern int testarr[3];
```

and define it in a cpp module.

```
int testarr[]={1,2,3};
```

The same is valid for other global variables that have external linkage.

As for this remark

> BTW, based on something else I found, I tried defining testarr as
>   extern but got the same problem.

Then the array with the specifier extern shall not be initialized in a header. Otherwise it is a definition of the array.

Answer (score 3):

When you put a variable definition into a header file, any .c file that includes it will have a copy of that variable.  When you then attempt to link them, you get a multiple definition error.

Your header files should contain only a **declaration** of the variable.  This is done using the `extern` keyword, and with no initializer.

Then in exactly one .c file, you put the definition along with an optional initializer.

For example:

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "fcn.h"

int a;
int testarr[]={1,2,3};

int main() {
   fcn();
   printf("HI\n");
}
```

stuff.h:

```
#ifndef STUFF
#define STUFF

extern int a;
extern int testarr[];

#endif
```

fcn.h:

```
#include "stuff.h"
extern int b[];
void fcn();
```

fcn.c:

```
#include "main.h"

int b[]={5,6,7};

void fcn() {
   printf("Hello\n");
}
```